# DRF: access serializer fields outside meta

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So, i need to get the "like" status on posts, and need my serialzier to return attr "liked" bool.

I am trying to get the current post being serialized, pass it into a query which will either return true or false.

The query is like:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    PostedByName = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='PostedBy.Name')
    PostedByUserName = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='PostedBy.user.username')
    current_user = serializers.SerializerMethodField('_user')
    # Use this method for the custom field
    def _user(self, obj):

        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        if request:
            CurrentUser = request.auth.user
            try:
                PostLikes.objects.get(Post = #post id, User = CurrentUser)
                return True
            except exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist:
                return False
    class Meta:
        model = Posts
        fields = ['PostedByName', 'PostedByUserName', 'Title', 'PostBody', 'Image1', 'Image2', 'Image3', 'PostedOn', 'Vote', 'CommentCount', 'current_user', 'id']
        read_only_fields = fields
```

Comment: Can you properly format your code?

Comment: Yes, done. My bad.

Comment: That's better, but you forgot now to mention what problem you're facing.

Comment: I need to pass in the id of the post currently being serialized to the query on PostLike

Comment: You have `obj` in `def _user(self, obj)` function. It is an object instance of Posts, just use it.
Use: `obj.id`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Don't know how I overlooked that.